# How to select the last x days before a specific event?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has the following columns:

- id - category
- timestamp -  datetime
- event - category

I want to create a window function that returns another dataframe with all the events that happened x days before a specific event, for each device.
For example:

```
Id   Timestamp    Event   
123   2018-11-01  click_page1
123   2018-12-24  buy   
123   2018-05-23  click_page2
133   2018-12-25  sign_in
133   2018-12-28  buy
133   2018-10-15  click
```

I would like to define a function that 
`filter_window(df, event_name, position, window)` where position can be the first or last time of the event and window is the number of days since that event time.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you want to determine the start and end dates based on position and window, then filter your dataframe using those boundaries.

The first is done with a knowledge of pandas datetime formats - please do look into the documentation for more details.

```
def filter_window(df, event_name, position, window):
    if position = 'first':
        end_date = df.loc[(df.Event = event_name),'Timestamp'].min()
    else:
        end_date = df.loc[(df.Event = event_name),'Timestamp'].max()
    start_date = end_date - pd.Timedelta(days=window)
    return df[(df.Timestamp >= start_date)&(df.Timestamp <= end_date)]
```

EDIT: This code obviously needs to be adapted to your needs. For example:

```
for i in list(set(df.Id)):
    df1 = df.loc[df.Id = i]
```

That's a for loop which makes one dataframe for each different `Id`. Then you can use the `filter_window` function on that dataframe to get what you need.

Comment: the idea works perfectly if you want to filter just for the min or max event date. But I'm interested in filtering x days before an event for *each id*. This means that the min/max date can't be across the whole dataframe, but the min/max for each id

Comment: Please see the edit. I don't know how much more I can do for you based on the limited information I have :S

Comment: In order to get the results I wanted I changed your code by grouping by 'id'   `df2 = df.loc[(df.event == event_name)].groupby('id').agg({'timestamp': 'min'})`